# wordpress The requested URL was not found

Tags: wordpress

When i set plain permalink to post name permalink then page url is not found.

How can i solve this ?

Comment: You've flushed your permalinks. The old one won't work. If you have that page in a menu, just go to your home page and follow the new link to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your .htaccess file , if you are using permalink rather than default then their should be a .htaccess file with the following code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Wordpress will add this by default but may be in some case that may be a permission issue or some server configuration , you have to add by manually. 
You can read more about wordpress .htaccess file [Click Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)